# On estimating $\exp(-iHt)$ when $H$ is perturbed

Tags: linear-algebra, quantum-mechanics, perturbation-theory, matrix-analysis

Let us assume that we have an *unbounded* Hamiltonian $H$ and we perturb it a bit to be $H'=H+ \varepsilon A$. I am sure that estimating $||\exp(-iHt) - \exp(-iH't)||$ belongs to the subject of perturbation theory. Can you recommend me some resource (preferably textbooks) dealing with the topic?

Comment: This doesn't strictly answer your question, but maybe the literature I cited in [this old answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4642487/) (mostly Chapter 9 ff. in Kato's "Perturbation Theory of Linear Operators") can be of use to you